# PHP how to unpack values from packed string

Tags: php, string, bit, pack

I have a "string" with packed binary data. I know, that each data element was originally let's say 14-bits value. So the string was constructed as sequence of these 14bit values without any bit gap - e.g.

bit 1.-14. = value1

bit 15.-28. = value2

etc.. Is there a simple way in PHP, how to restore original values or do I have to cycle through the string with some bit masking and shifting?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: [Unpack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) in PHP

Comment: Not sure, I reviewed all format parameters before posting the question, but non of them looks like what I am looking for. Unfortunately I don't see there an option, which allows me to say, that let's say each original integer value is stored e.g. in 5 bits ....

Comment: Hmm I tought it could be done with the `unpack()` function, but it seems a totally different issue wich I don't have an answer for, sorry:( @user3523426